# Create a fishnet inside an a symmetric polygon using ArcGIS desktop 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.3, vector-grid

I try to create a fishnet with 5 columns and 3 rows to this polygon:

[image]

but i get this result:

[image]

whereas is wanted the grid will be adjusted to the polygon direction like this :

[image]

Comment: Try using spatial adjustment to rotate your fishnet

Comment: i have only desktop licence.

Comment: Create Fishnet allows you to angle your grid by using the second pair of XY coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

[Esri Help File link](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/how-create-fishnet-works.htm)

Look at the "Angle of Rotation" section on the link, I followed the steps and it was really easy to rotate